# Regarding detaching a tube from a valve on the top of a water storage tank

Tags: plumbing, water, valve, water-tank, water-filtration

I am trying to perform the tank sanitizing operation for the reverse osmosis system. One of the procedures involves detaching the tube from the valve, as shown in the first figure. The document does not specify how to do this? Would you like to let me know how to do this? Besides, the second figure shows the tank label and a blue component. I do not know what is that blue component used for? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quick connector. Water pressure actually pushes the locking mechanism to hold the tube in.

With the pressure completely relieved you can press the grey ring around the blue tube inward and at the same time pull the tube out.

Comment: I agree but many times it helps to push in on the tube and the ring this helps it to release then while maintaining pressure on the ring pull out.

Comment: I just checked the web site and that is a bladder based pressure tank from the web page view the top section has the air and the bottom the water but these look upside down to yours so I may be wrong. [web page](http://www.pacificwaterinc.com/siteresource/site_108102/customize/image/flexconfrotanks.pdf) the blue item in the web page view looks like it might be a drain but it was not identified. In any case if it is a pressure tank and you release the air it will need to be recharged with air. this can be done with a hand pump but will take quite a while.

Comment: He shouldn't need to release the air. I've had one of these tanks before.  Just drain it and the pressure will be off the fitting.  Also it probably looks upside down because the water fitting is actually center bottom and the tanks sits in a stand. @EdBeal